# How to get rows from csv file that only have numerical values (without english letters)?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I want to get rows from CSV files that only include numbers. My input file looks like this:

```
8.1.0,289,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,260,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,207,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,206,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Note,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,194,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8.1.0,184,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

it should able to get the numbers have above format like `9`, `9.0.0`, `8.1` etc.

How can I use `csvgrep` or `awk` or `sed` command for this? The CSV file have two columns. It should omit the lines which have any letter in them.

Comment: `9.0.0` is not a valid number, and in some locales this is a single number `10,194` with comma as thousands separator, and two different numbers `10` and `194` without that.

Comment: Your question title says "_How to get rows from csv file that only have numerical values (without english letters)?_" but your question body then changes the requirement. What about valid numbers such as `1.0e2` or non-English letters such as αβ? What about invalid numbers such as `9.0.0`? Do you want to handle explicitly signed values (i.e. with a leading `+` or `-`)?

Comment: I had to work large number of dataset which containes details about andriod versions.those versions normally mention in a format 8.0.0,8.0.1 etc.that is why I am looking for special way to grep them.I only found way to grep the fully integer values.

Comment: You say `The CSV file have two columns` - then why are there about 20 commas per row in your sample input? In your real data are there perhaps 2 columns you want analyzed and several additional columns you do not want analyzed? If so, please [edit] your question to show more truly representative sample input and expected output. If there truly are only 2 columns in your data then get rid of all those spurious trailing commas in your example.

Comment: there is a problem with libreoffice calc.The original data set consisted with few other columns.For my requirement they do not need.I deleted whole columns.When I open the file with normal text editor it shows that number of commas.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `grep` command, like this:

```
grep -v "[A-Za-z]" filename > filename.output
```

Here is the test:

```
# cat zz2
1;2
a,1
2,B
                                                                                                                   
# grep -v "[A-Za-z]" zz2
1;2
```

To filter empty lines you can use:

```
grep -v "[A-Za-z]" zz2 | grep -v '^$'
```

Comment: How to get this egrep output  to another csv file

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga, check my edited answer

Comment: it is working.Do you have any idea how to sed or grep values like 8.0,8.0.0 .I find a way but is it not easy.

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga, if you are happy with the answer please consider to mark it as accepted. If you have another question please consider to create new

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk` and to validate that all the fields are contains a valid numbers and skip empty fields.

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i+0!=$i && $i!="") next }1' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

```
LC_ALL=C grep -v '[^0123456789,.]' < in.csv > out.csv
```

Would remove the lines that contain any character other than `0123456789,.`. With `LC_ALL=C`, we make sure all sequences of bytes form valid characters. In the `C` locale (but often not other locales), it should be safe to replace `0123456789` with `0-9`.

For stricter matching that mandates lines to be sequences of 0 or more `,` separated fields consisting of `.`-separate lists of 0 or more sequences of 1 or more decimal digits, with GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -xP '((\d+(\.\d+)*)?)(,(?1))*' < in.csv > out.csv
```

Or POSIX:

```
number=[0123456789]+
field="($number(\\.$number)*)?"
LC_ALL=C grep -xE "$field(,$field)*" < in.csv > out.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

with `sed` and the `d` command:

```
sed '/[a-zA-Z]/d' data
```

Delete all the line if, at least, one character is found.

With `awk`:

```
awk '!/[a-zA-Z]/' data
```

Avoid printing if at least a character is found inside the line.

Comment: The pattern: `!/[a-zA-Z]/` is a short form for : `$0!~/../` ?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
 $ awk '/^[0-9.,]+$/' input
```

This command is written as suggested by @EdMorton.

Another method:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
if ($i ~  /^(\-?[0-9.]+)([eE]\-?[0-9.]+)?$/   || $i == "");
else $0=""};
(NF)' input
```

Or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
if ($i ~  /^(\-?[0-9.]+)([eE]\-?[0-9.]+)?$/   || $i == "") ;
else next}1' input
```

In above command, if regex in not found then current input record(`$0`) is set to empty string(`""`). Next `(NF)` or `{if (NF > 0) print}` will print all non-empty lines. In second command, in else statement `next` prevents any action on records where regex is not matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^[0-9.,]+$/' input.csv
8.1.0,289,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,260,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,207,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,206,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,194,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8.1.0,184,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

this prints lines that contain **ONLY** digits, periods, and commas.  Any other character appearing anywhere on a line will prevent that line from being printed.

Comment: The sed code works by chance only. If consecutive bad lines come the second shall be printed.